# How to construct this modular Galois representation?

Tags: modular-forms, galois-representations

I want to know how to construct this modular Galois representation:

1. The $\bmod p$ representation is semi-simple.
2. For any lattice $T$ , $\dfrac{T}{p^{3}T}$ does not have a $G$-stable cyclic subgroup of order $p^3$ (i.e., there does not exist the congruence equation $a_\ell=\ell^{s}+\ell^{t} \bmod p^3$ (for prime $\ell\neq p$)

Comment: What is $G$? Is it the absolute Galois group of a number field? Then any representation which is surjective mod $p$ will do, and the mod $p$ representation of a non-CM elliptic curve has this property for almost all $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much!But could you give me an example of the representation attached to modular forms?

Comment: Well, you could use a modular elliptic curve, for instance. (Or one can prove similar surjectivity results for arbitrary modular forms of weight $\ge 2$, cf. several well-known articles by Ribet.)

Comment: Apologize for replying late. I understand and thank you very much! Actually I am studying Number Theory, but not going well. I shall train harder.Thank you!